# Unsuccessful Logins

Tags: php

So when the user unsuccessfully logs in for the first time it performs the tasks 70-73 and then it jumps down to 111. That part works correctly however when the chances left gets to 0 meaning the failedLogins value in the db would be 5 its supposed to do the steps starting at line 76 but it doesn't. Instead it shows 0 for the chances left and then that's it. I'm sure my logic is right but the the code is just placed in the wrong places.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/p3n1Fr78)

```
// User is registered and verified

                $query = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

                $lockDate = $row['lockDate'];

                // Find out if user is locked out of their account
                if (($lockDate !== "0000-00-00 00:00:00") AND (strtotime($lockDate) <= time())) {

                    $currentDateTime = time();
                    $minutes = floor(($currentDateTime-$lockDate) / 60);

                    // Take minutes and perform tasks
                    if ($lockDate > 0 && $minutes < 10) {

                        // Calculate time remaining
                        $timeRemaining = 10 - $minutes;

                        // Account locked error
                        $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => 'Your account is currently locked, we appologize for the inconvienence. You must wait ' .$timeRemaining.' minutes before you can log in again!');

                    } else {

                        // Clear the lock
                        $query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET lockDate = NULL, hackerIPAddress = NULL, failedLogins = 0 WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

                    } 

                } else {

                    // Escape post data
                    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,$_POST['password']);

                    // Assign hashed password to variable
                    $regenFromPostPW = reGenPassHash($password, $passwordDB2);

                    // Comparing the database password with the posted password
                    if ($passwordDB == $regenFromPostPW) {

                        $query2 = "UPDATE manager_users_logins SET numberOfLogins = numberOfLogins + 1, lastOnline = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                        $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);

                        // Assign user data into an array
                        $loggedinUserDataArray = array('userID' => $userID, 'name' => $firstName . " " . $lastName);

                        // Assign user data array to new session
                        $_SESSION['user_data'] = $loggedinUserDataArray;

                        // See if the remember me checkbox was checked
                        if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {

                            // Sets an expiration time for the cookie
                            $myExpiration = time()+60*60*24*100;

                            // Sets the cookie for the username
                            setcookie("username", $username, $myExiration, "/");

                        }

                        // Succesful login complete
                        $output = array('errorsExist' => false, 'message' => 'You have been logged in, please allow a moment while we load your account data!');

                    } else {

                        // Login unsuccessful

                        $query = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                        $failedLogins = $row['failedLogins'];

                        // Take failed logins and compare it 
                        if ($row['failedLogins'] >= 5) {

                            // Retrieve IP Address of user trying to hack into account
                            $hackerIPAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

                            // Update database after account getting hacked and run query
                            $query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET lockDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, hackerIPAddress = '".$hackerIPAddress."' WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

                            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM manager_users WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
                            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                            $firstName = $row['firstName'];
                            $lastName = $row['lastName'];

                            // Email user new registration account
                            function my_domain_name() {
                                $my_domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
                                $my_domain = str_replace('www.', '', $my_domain);
                                return $my_domain;
                            }
                            $sender_email = "noreply@kansasoutlawwrestling.com";
                            $reply_to = "noreply@kansasoutlawwrestling.com";
                            $recipient_email = $email; 
                            $email_subject = "KOW Manager Account Locked";

                            $email_body = 'Hello '.$firstName.' '.$lastName.' You, or someone using your account at '.my_domain_name().', has attempted to hack into your account. If this is an error, ignore this email and you will be removed from our mailing list.<br /><br />Regards, '.my_domain_name().' Team';

                            mailSomeone($email, $sender_email, $email_subject, $email_body);

                            // Account locked error
                            $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => 'Your account is currently locked, we appologize for the inconvienence. This is a security messure implimented by to many failed login\'s! You must wait 10 minutes before you can login again!');         

                        } else {

                            $query = "UPDATE manager_users_logins_hacking SET failedLogins = '".$failedLogins."'+ 1 WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                            $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);

                            $query2 = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
                            $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
                            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                            $failedLogins = $row2['failedLogins'];

                            // Calculate how many chances the user has to login before account gets locked
                            $chancesLeft = 5 - $failedLogins;

                            // Invalid username and password error 
                            $output = array('errorsExist' => true, 'message' => 'Invalid Username and Password combination! You have ' .$chancesLeft.' chances left to login succesfully or the account will be locked!'); 

                        }

                    }

                }
```

Comment: Code is hard to understand because it have many if's and mixes sql queries, validation and business logic. As I see you provide line numbers to help readers understand what you expect, but SO doesn't shows line numbers and pastebin "is under heavy load right now" so this not helps for us. I suggest to refactor code first and then you should see where your bug, or show code for us again and we will try to help to you.

Answer (score 0):

I try to debug your code and I suppose that code is right and does exactly what your describe. But it shows misleading message due to small bug: you execute update query and increment counter to one and after you select this value and use it in calculation. You should use old value in calculation, not a new one. Isn't it?

To fix this you may remove following useless lines:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM manager_users_logins_hacking WHERE userID = '".$userID."'";
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbc,$query2);
$row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
$failedLogins = $row2['failedLogins'];
```

Answer (score 0):

$lockDate is a datestring sometimes, and sometimes you try to subtract with it.
$currentDateTime = time();
$minutes = floor(($currentDateTime-$lockDate) / 60);

either this is a problem or strtotime($lockdate) above will be a problem.